# python3 cannot save to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

it supposed to collect data from website and save it to database, it can collect data but cannot save it, I have tested connection between mysql is work fine, but it cannot be save. someone please help...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
from urllib import parse

import MySQLdb

db_connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', db='database', user='root', passwd='123321') 

cursor = db_connection.cursor()

url = "https://srh.bankofchina.com/search/whpj/search_cn.jsp"
Form_Data = {}
Form_Data['erectDate'] = ''
Form_Data['nothing'] = ''
Form_Data['pjname'] = '欧元'
data = parse.urlencode(Form_Data).encode('utf-8')
html = request.urlopen(url,data).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'BOC_main publish'})
table = div.find('table')
tr = table.find_all('tr')
td = tr[1].find_all('td')
c_name = td[0].text.strip()
c_updated = td[3].text.strip()
print(td[0].get_text(),td[3].get_text(),td[6].get_text())

sql = ("INSERT INTO currency_rate(c_name,c_updated)" "VALUES (%s,%s)" %(c_name,c_updated))

try:

   cursor.execute(sql)

   db_connection.commit()
except:

   db_connection.rollback()


db_connection.close()
```

that is error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\Python38\test1.py", line 33, in 
cursor.execute(sql)
File "D:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 191, in execute
query = query.encode(db.encoding)
File "D:\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 52-53: character maps to

Comment: Try `except Exception as e:` and `print(e)` in your try/accept. It may be that an exception is raised and it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a unicode decode/encode error. Have a look at the [docs on the subject](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).

From what I can see on the traceback, it seems that your database uses an encoding that do not support some of ythe characters you are trying to save.

Try change the encoding of your database (also called [collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-database.html) in MySql world) or `encode` your strings into something that your db can accept before executing the query.

p.s. : it also seem that your sql is a little malformed, looks like you are missing a couple apexes:

try modify this line:

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO currency_rate(c_name,c_updated)" "VALUES (%s,%s)" %(c_name,c_updated))
```

into:

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO currency_rate(c_name,c_updated)" "VALUES ('%s','%s')" %(c_name,c_updated))
```

Comment: I think so too, but I don't know where do I add encoding tab...

Comment: in Mysql you have to create the db declaring a character set, like so: CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;. It is also good practice to declare charset in table definitions: CREATE TABLE mytable ( ... ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;